What is the time base of ros2 loggers?
I was reading about logging here:
https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Logging.html
I notice in my log file some type of time is output in front of the strings I write to the logger.
What time base is being used? System time? Sim time? It's not clear.

The logging output handler is called here and is passed a time variable now as an argument. now is initialized here by call of rcutils_system_time_now(), which reads the system time.
So there is no out of the box solution to have sim time instead of system time.
If you want to study the logging subsystem, this documentation —though not fully up to date anymore— can be helpful.
